# bash rename file/add integer in filename with various extensions in multiple subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell, file-rename, quoting, subdirectory

I want to insert an integer into filenames with various extensions in multiple subdirectories using bash.

Examples:

- `./trial2/foo.hhh` --> `./trial2/foo1.hhh`
- `./trial2/trial3/foo.txt`-->  `./trial2/trial3/foo1.txt`

I tried to separate the filename from the extension and insert the integer in between with:

```
i=123
find . -type f -exec sh -c ' echo mv "$0" "${0%.*}${i}.${0##*.}" ' {} \;
mv ./trial2/foo.hhh ./trial2/foo.hhh
```

But the variable output `${i}` is not printed. Why?
If I change to:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c ' mv "$0" "${0%.*}123.${0##*.}" ' {} \;
mv ./trial2/foo.hhh ./trial2/foo123.hhh
```

The number is printed.  However, I need the variable `${i}` as it will be defined in a wrapping for-loop.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Thanks for reading the tour - not everyone does :) .  You can also visit the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52483910/edit) to include more information if necessary.

Comment: BTW, another option is to `export i`, which will make it available in all subprocess shells without needing to explicitly pass it through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit

You are almost there; you just hit a quoting subtlety.  `i` is declared in the current shell, so needs to be passed into the `sh` run by `find` somehow.  In your current command, `${i}` is in single quotes, so is not interpreted by `bash` before the quoted material is passed to `sh`.

As suggested by Charles Duffy:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c ' echo mv "$0" "${0%.*}${1}.${0##*.}" ' {} "$i" \;
```

Within the `sh` command, `$0` is the `{}`, as you know.  `$1` is the second parameter to the `sh`, which is `"$i"` (`i` expanded as a single word).  Instead of `${i}`, the `sh` command uses `${1}` to access that parameter (a copy of `i`).

#### Original

In this example, `i` is interpolated in the current shell.

```
Before: find . -type f -exec sh -c ' echo mv "$0" "${0%.*}${i}.${0##*.}" ' {} \;
After:  find . -type f -exec sh -c ' echo mv "$0" "${0%.*}'"${i}"'.${0##*.}" ' {} \;
                                                          ^^    ^^
```

The `'"${i}"'` drops you out of the single quotes, then expands `i`, then takes you back into the single quotes.  That way the command you are passing to `sh` includes the value of `i` you want.

Comment: there is an error in your Example: `~/foo$ find . -type f -exec sh -c ' echo mv "$0" "${0%.*}${i}.${0##*.}" ' {} \;` should produce the output
`mv ./trial2/foo.hhh ./trial2/foo.hhh` not `mv ./trial2/foo.hhh ./trial2/foo123.hhh`

Comment: @joboog Thanks for flagging it - removed to avoid future confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `$i` in `$0`, and your filenames in `$1` and onward, and you can change from `-exec ... {} \;` to `-exec ... {} +`, thus using only one `sh` instance to rename potentially several files.

The following requires bash, but generates `mv` commands that are guaranteed to be correct even in the presence of malicious or confusing filenames (with spaces, newlines, control characters, etc):

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c '
  logcmd() { printf "%q " "$@"; printf "\n"; }  # a more accurate replacement for echo
  for f; do
    logcmd mv "$f" "${f%.*}${0}.${f##*.}"
  done' "$i" {} +
```

Comment: Well, "guaranteed to be correct" is strong language --- a bad actor running this in `/etc` could make it very difficult to log in unless `login(1)` knew to read `/etc/passwd123` :D  "Guaranteed to be executed correctly by `bash`," sure.

Comment: "Safe against code injection attempts from malicious filenames", let's put it there. :)